# Customising model returned in view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Usually in a django view you would do something like

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.something()
```

How do I get more control over the shape of the object returned. Sorry for the heresy, but in ASP.Net MVC (I only quote this because I'm more familiar with it), I would do something like.

```
from e in MyModel
  select new {
    e.Field1,
    e.Field2
  }
```

I'm looking to do something similar in Django. I'm using backbone so need to re-shape the model where I would usually use tags in my templates.

Comment: A view is just Python code. You can do anything you like in it. If you need to return a custom object, then just iterate through and build it up as you want.

Comment: Hi Daniel - yes thanks but I am really looking for a more prescriptive way of doing it than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a such called `Managers`.
[Official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance) has pretty good description.
I'd recommend you to read 'Pro Django' book by Apress.